# Check if string contains atleast one XML node

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How can I check if a string contains at least one xmlNode. The string may or may not be a valid XML. Is there any way other than checking for "<" or ">" in the string.

Thanks

Comment: *"may or may not be [...] XML"* -- Are you still interested in the string if it is *not* XML?

Comment: yes,my scenario is like that.Otherwise checking would have been simple

Comment: You are not being clear enough. Please give a few sample strings and tell what you want to do with each of them.

Comment: The response from  web service can be a string with valid XML/Invalid XML or can it can just be a simple plain text without any XML content. I want to check if the response received contains any xmlnode. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: Do you know what could be the name of xmlnode to be searched? if its not a valid xml, then you have to parse the whole string in finding the correct match.

Comment: If you just want to find out if it is XML or not, try to build an XmlDocument from it. If that fails, it's not XML. I wonder more what *"contains"* could mean in this context. What's a string worth that *"contains XML nodes"*?

Comment: @zenwalker: I will not know the name of xmlnode 
@Tomalak: The response can be something like 'The search for A= 1 and B= 34 did not return any results' or It can be a string containing valid/invalid XML(Like some times the root node might me missing...even though all other nodes are present)

Comment: Well if you dont know what to search, then doing a pattern matching is all you have to do.

Comment: A string never contains a node, it can only contain tags. The tags become nodes when the string is parsed. To determine what the parsed string will turn into when parsed, you have to parse it. If parsing fails, you can catch the exception.

Comment: @Michael - I was actually doing the same. As the response text sometimes didn't contain any tag it was throwing exception during parsing. I had to show a different error before parsing when the response didn't contain any tag. As zenwalker suggested I have used pattern matching. If there is a match then I am passing the text...otherwise I am showing a different message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex will work (cue laughter), there is one caveat. This regex will not tell you if there's more than one valid element, just that there is at least one valid element.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"<([^>]+)>[^<]*</(\1)>");

        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("<a>One Element</a>").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("<a>Not An Element</b>").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("<a>One Element</a><b>Two Element</b><c>Red Element</c><d>Blue Element</d>").ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: It may not be sufficient enough to check whether there are matching closing tags. Examples of other things that needs to be checked:
1) A tag name must be a QName (prefix and name part OR just the name part) 2) A tag can be closed in the start tag e.g. <MyTag/>

Comment: Yeah. The empty tag method would add a second layer of complexity to the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of SamuelWarren's answer,
this one handles optional attributes.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"<([^\s^>]+)\s*[^>]*>[^<]*</(\1)>");

        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("<a>One Element</a>").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">One Element</a>").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" id=\"whatever\" class=\"ui-link\">One Element</a>").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("<a>Not An Element</b>").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("<a>One Element</a><b>Two Element</b><c>Red Element</c><d>Blue Element</d>").ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```